# Create matrix from a column vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a column vector with 19176 values. I want to create a matrix with 136 values in each row so I can have a 141*136 matrix (19176/136 = 141). The matrix should take the first 136 values for the first row and the next 136 values for the second row etc.

Comment: `mat = reshape(vec,[136,141]).';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *reshape* the column vector?

`out=reshape(in,136,141).'`

Comment: I think that way the first 136 values go to the first column rather than the first row, `out = reshape(in,[136,141]).';` will do.

Comment: @user2999345 yup, I did not even look at that, you are right

Comment: @ShaibalAhmed consider acepting th enaswer as valid